# Laravel 5.4 Raw Join Query

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, left-join

I have a table `TBL_POST` used to store blog posts. A post can be assigned to multiple categories, there is a column, **cat_id** that stores category ID's in comma separated pattern like **2,4,6**. I want to use **FIND_IN_SET()** method in this line

```
->leftJoin(TBL_CAT.' as c', 'p.cat_id', '=', 'c.id')
```

to show the associated category names. How can I do that?

```
public static function getPostWithJoin($status="")
{
    $query = DB::table(TBL_POST .' as p')
            ->select('p.id','p.post_title','p.post_status','u.name as author','c.name as cat_name','p.updated_at')
            ->leftJoin(TBL_ADMINS.' as u', 'p.post_author', '=', 'u.id')
            ->leftJoin(TBL_CAT.' as c', 'p.cat_id', '=', 'c.id')
            ->where('p.post_type','post');
    if($status!="all") {
        $query->where('p.post_status',$status); 
    }

    $query->orderby('p.id','DESC');
    $data = $query->paginate(20);

    return $data;       
}
```

Comment: its bad approach to save many to many relation, better to create a 3rd table tbl_cat_post where you save post_id and cat_id only from here you can join, category and post tables,

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @umefarooq . i'm thinking about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callback to create more complicated join query.

```
->leftJoin(TBL_CAT, function($query){
     $query->on(TBL_CAT.'id', '=', 'p.cat_id')->where("**", "**", "**");
})
```

Here is link on laravel doc - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins "Advanced Join Clauses" section.

UPD:: 
As mentioned in comment it is not good idea to have string for such types of data. Cause search by equality should be much simpler than string check. Even if your amount of data should not have big difference, you never know what will happen with your app in future.

But if you still want to do that i think you can try like this

```
->leftJoin(TBL_CAT, function($query){
     $query->where(DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(".TBL_CAT.".id, p.cat_id)"), "<>", "0");
})
```

Join that will check existence of id in cat_id.

Comment: Edited a little bit.

Comment: Thanks @Anton M , i will try this. yes its not good idea but i have to join 5 tables if i use separate tables for terms and post relation. that's why i'm using this method. and i think there will not be any problem because it will store just few IDs, just to display what category the post belongs to.

Comment: i tried the your suggestion it worked but, a post display two times with different categories. like 
[Id] = 1
[post] = test
[category] = cat1

And 
[Id] = 1
[post] = test
[category] = cat2

i want this, like [category] = cat1,cat2 or in array.

Comment: About 5 tables in join, i don't think this solution is better, cause you still join category table and also for each perform search with string function instead of indexed number field. For posts group query by post_id.

Comment: i did not understand your suggestion can you elaborate please. And when i used `groupBy('p.id') ` , i got error  `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'test.p.post_title' isn't in GROUP BY`

Comment: Usually databases require that you group by all fields you want to select, or use aggregation to calculate values (otherwise it is not possible to decide what to take), old versions of mysql allowed to do that without marking everything in group by.

Comment: About join, in my opinion there are quite many problems:
1. Foreign key check does not exists, so you can put almost any thing there, even text.
2. In terms of performance i think join by indexed integer should be faster than join by string (even if string is indexed) with function performed on value.

Comment: Thank you @Anton M.