# What is wrong with this laravel query with left join?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a laravel project(Laravel 6.8). I have a locations table and a dashboards table. I am trying to build a query that will return all matching records from the dashboards table. Looking at another SO question([Laravel 5.4 Raw Join Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262030/laravel-5-4-raw-join-query)), I saw a similar need and tried to adjust the code to fit my needs, but it still doesn't work.
This is what I have right now.

```
  $locations = DB::table('locations')
     ->selectRaw("site_name,
      COUNT(DISTINCT client) as client_count,
      GROUP_CONCAT(client_lob) as lobs,
      COUNT(DISTINCT client_lob) as lob_count,
      SUM(agent_workstations) as aw_sum,
     SUM(production_support_workstations) as psw_sum,
    locations.*" )
       ->leftJoin('dashboards', 'locations.id', '=', 'dashboards.location_id')

     ->whereNotNull('latitude')
    ->groupBy(['site_name'])
    ->orderBy('site_name', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

It returns only the data from locations without returning anything from dashboards. I can't see what is wrong with this query. Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: because you never select the dashboard's fields

Comment: I need to call it a night and go to sleep. @TsaiKoga, make that an answer instead of a comment and I will accept it. I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: what's fields' name in table `dashboards`? or what's field do u want from dashboards?

Comment: @TsaiKoga, no, you are correct. That is what I was missing. I completely overlooked that. If you will make your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I have post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you never select the dashboard's fields, try to select the dashboard's field like this:

```php
$locations = DB::table('locations')
     ->selectRaw("site_name,
      COUNT(DISTINCT client) as client_count,
      GROUP_CONCAT(client_lob) as lobs,
      COUNT(DISTINCT client_lob) as lob_count,
      SUM(agent_workstations) as aw_sum,
     SUM(production_support_workstations) as psw_sum,
    locations.*, dashboards.column1, dashboards.column2" )
```